# Jenkins git publisher permission

Tags: git, jenkins

I create a jenkins job. Configure as below:

- Git

  Repository URL:ssh://jenkins@******.git

  Credentials:jenkins(jenkins key for gerrit)

  Branch to build:*/module_verified
- Git publisher

  Force Push:checked

  Tags to push:release-$BUILD_NUMBER

  Create new tag:checked

  Update new tag:checked

  Target remote name:origin

Trying to set jenkins admin in gerrit also didn't resolve the issue.
Does anyone know the cause of the error? qwq

Comment: Looks like `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email` on the machine running Jenkins does not match the user it logs in with. Check your settings against what gerrit expects. Also, Jenkins should really NOT be admin in gerrit... just give it the mentioned `Forge Commiter` permission if you can't resolve it any other way.

Comment: I also tried to give "Forge Commiter" permission, but still couldn't solve the problem.